# Python Celery weird behavior when routing tasks to specific RabbitMQ queues

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I was banging my head on this for a while and I still could not figure out what the issue is. I am trying to route different tasks to their own specific queues. In RabbitMQ, I have the default `celery` queue and another queue named `test_queue`. I can push tasks into the `celery` just fine, but I am having trouble figuring out how to push tasks into the `test_queue` queue. I have read the documentation for the celery settings `task_default_queue`, `task_queue`, and `task_routes`.

`celery.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('celery_test',
    broker_url='amqp://',
    backend='amqp://',
    include=['celery_test.tasks'],
    worker_max_tasks_per_child=1,
    task_create_missing_queues=True,
    #task_queues = {'test_queue': {'exchange': 'test_queue', 'routing_key': 'test_queue'}},
    #task_routes = {'celery_test.tasks.test': {'queue': 'test_queue'}}
    #task_default_queue='test_queue'
    )

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(result_expires=3600,)
app.conf.task_routes = {'celery_test.tasks.test': {'queue': 'test_queue'}}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

I noticed that when I specify the `test_queue` queue name in the `Celery` constructor, my tasks do not get properly routed to the correct RabbitMQ queue. Instead, I had to use `app.conf.task_routes = {'celery_test.tasks.test': {'queue': 'test_queue'}}` to get the job done. I know this seems trivial but I have been beating my head on this for hours and I cannot figure out why one method works but not the other.

Here is my celeryconfig.py

```
    broker_url="amqp://"
    result_backend="amqp://"
    include=["tasks"]
    task_acks_late=True
    task_default_rate_limit="150/m"
    task_time_limit=300
    worker_prefetch_multiplier=1
    worker_max_tasks_per_child=2
    task_routes={'tasks.test': {'queue': 'test_queue'}}
```

I am using

- 4.3.0 (rhubarb)
- Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Celery 4.x (class) constructor does not take those parameters you mentioned (task_queues, task_routes and task_default_queue).

Comment: would adding those particular parameters to a config file work?

Comment: I tried adding `task_routes = {'tasks.test': {'queue': 'test_queue'}}` to my `celeryconfig.py` last night and it did not work. The task got sent to the default `celery` queue in RabbitMQ instead of `test_queue`

I made an edit to show my `celeryconfig.py`

Comment: If you want particular task to be sent to particular queue, you can put that in the annotation (decorator).